# No git 'hooks' folder being created on Windows

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Having installed git for Windows, and also having tried SourceTree, neither one creates a hooks folder in the .git folder when I create a repository.

These are the contents of .git folders on my machine:

```
Folders:
    logs
    objects
    refs

Files:
    COMMIT_EDITMSG
    config
    FETCH_HEAD
    HEAD
    index
    ms-persist.xml
    ORIG_HEAD
    sourcetreeconfig
```

My knowledge of git is far from complete, but the only reference I've found is an unanswered question on [atlassion.com](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/15274798/why-is-there-no-hooks-folder-on-my-git-repository)

Can git hooks be run on Windows? And if so, how?

Comment: Yes, they can be run on Windows.  The repositories I've created all have a hooks directory - what _is_ in your .git folder?

Comment: @BJMyers I added more detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes git hooks can be run on Windows.*

---

As you see the image, I have a `git` folder for repository called `dev` under which I have a .git *(this is basically a hidden folder so to see, you have to enable show/check hidden items)*. Under this you can find all the hooks of your `repository`.

[image]

#### Read the content of hook

You can also read the content of `hook` file by opening it with any `text-editor`. This will allow you to enable `hook` or activate some `codes` by `uncommenting` it.

[image]

Hope you find it useful!

Thanks!

Comment: I can see that, unlike me, you have a hooks folder.